# Process Manager Pattern in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, eip

Does the Apache Camel framework offer support the Process Manager Pattern?
(http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ProcessManager.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can use the dynamic router
http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html

And then keep state on the `exchange` which the dynamic router accesses to determine the next step.

When you are *done* then the next step should be evaluated as `null`.